# Jquery help creating ajax link rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an ajaxlink, but it is not working:

My html:

```
<td class="apris"><p><a class="current desc" href="/?direction=asc&amp;sort=pris">Pris pr. md.</a></p></td>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('.apris').live('change', function() {
        var form=$(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:"\/finder\/" + $(this).val(),
          data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you expect a `td.onchange` to do?

Comment: Try `$('.apris a').live('click'...`

Comment: You said it "is not working" but didn't specify the expected nor the actual behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, because your code doesn't really match up with what you're trying to do, but maybe you want:

```
$('.apris a').live('click', function() {
        var form=$(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:"\/finder\/" + $(this).val(),
          data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
          }
          return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I want var form=$(this).closest('form'); to be the URL of the link not the form

Comment: The url of the link would be $('.apris a').attr('href');

Comment: ...also `$(this).attr('href')`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$('.apris a').live('click', function() {
        var form=$(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url: $(this).attr("href"),
          data:form.serialize(),
          success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
          }
          return false;
        });
    });
```